# Android path copy constructor fails?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In a toy graphics app I'm playing with I have something like this:

```
Path p = new Path();
p.addCircle(40,40,40,Path.Direction.CW);
canvas.drawPath(p);
```

This works as expected on both emulator and phone. But now I try this:

```
Path p = new Path();
p.addCircle(40,40,40,Path.Direction.CW);
Path q = new Path(p);
canvas.drawPath(q);
```

This works as expected on the emulator, but does nothing whatsoever on my Nexus S running 4.04.

Similarly, if I try:

```
Path p = new Path();
p.addCircle(40,40,40,Path.Direction.CW);
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setTranslate(50,50);
Path q = new Path();
p.transform(m,q);
canvas.drawPath(q);
```

Again this only works on the emulator, not on my phone. What is the problem here? No exceptions, nothing useful in the logs, execution runs right through the relevant code.

Comment: Have you tried pinpointing the value in a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

I expect this is failing because of hardware acceleration.  Try switching it off as a quick test.

I have just come across a similare issue in a ploting library I use.  The issue looks to be related to the multiple new Path() calls it had in it's drawing code.  I have pulled them out to the constructor where they really belong and things are now working OK.

Comment: Same problem here. Yes, it's caused by hardware acceleration bugs. But ... if I disable hardware-acceleration, I hit bugs in the software acceleration :(.